# how to use ->unique() on a paginated object to remove all duplicates in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a paginated collection in my laravel like below:

```php
$data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
    ->allowedFilters([
        AllowedFilter::scope('bed_count'),
        AllowedFilter::scope('filter_price'),
        AllowedFilter::scope('filter_date'),
        AllowedFilter::scope('discounts'),
        AllowedFilter::scope('name'),
        AllowedFilter::exact('grade_stars'),
        AllowedFilter::exact('city_id'),
        AllowedFilter::exact('is_recommended'),
        AllowedFilter::exact('accommodation_type_id'),
        AllowedFilter::scope('accommodation_facility')
//                'name',
    ])
    ->allowedAppends(['cheapestroom'])
    ->allowedIncludes(['gallery','city','accommodationRooms','accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistorySearch','discounts','prices'])
    ->allowedSorts([
        AllowedSort::custom('discount', new DiscountSort() ,'amount'),
        AllowedSort::custom('price', new PriceSort() ,'price'),
    ])
    ->paginate(10);
```

now if i use `->unique` on my `$data` it will only return me the 10 first result on dont show the other results i dont want to remove paginate from my collection because it would be so heavy object to call like 5k records and i dont want to use join as long as it cause other problems for me ,  so my question is that : is it possible to unique a paginated object in laravel or in resource maybe ??

Comment: did you try using groupBy()

Comment: yes i did its a bit complicated it wont work because it combines with 5 other joins

Comment: We can't answer your problem if you don't tell us what's your code really is. Because you're not using Laravel code, there is no `QueryBuilder::for()` in Laravel.

Comment: Its an spatie package query builder